# Excel - Number issues

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to put 13:73 in the cell, but everytime I put that and I click enter, it will automatically change to 0.592361. I went to format cells to see if I can get back 13:73 but that did not work.

How can I do this? I don't want 13:73 to be automatically change. I want to enter 13:73 in a cell.

Comment: Change the cell to `Text` before entering the data.

Comment: or prefix the data with `'`: `'13:73` which will force it to be text.

Comment: What is in that cell? A formula? What type format??

Answer (score 3):

What happens:
If you put `=(13*60+73)/(24*60)` in a cell, you will see `0.592361...` displayed as you press enter.
Excel interprets your entry as a HH:MM time, but as it is 'awkward' (not a normal 'time') the interpretation ends as something else than expected, of some strange reason. Leaving the time as a decimal value, which corresponds to how big portion 13 hours plus 73 minutes is of 24 hours. If you set the format f that cell to "Time" and select a 24 hour format you will see "14:13" which is 73 minutes past "13:00".

As has been stated in the comments, `'` as the first character will make whatever you type "stay" as is. The same will happen if you first set the cell to be "text" - hold CTRL and hit 1, then select text in the dialog.